# Overflow content auto inside overflow hidden?

Tags: css, overflow

I have a div with `height in %` and `overflow: hidden;`. Inside a div with `overflow: auto` doesn't show scroll when content is big.

Is it posible to do that i want?

Live: http://indorio.ru/inside-box.html (#overlay-box fluid with height of %)

Answer (score 12):

Overflow requires a height to be specified, otherwise the element will wrap its contents. Depending on your situation you could specify the height as 100%:

```
#outer {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
#inner {
  height: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
#scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
#content {
  height:400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xe7k/